# Prove composite is smooth given condition on derivative

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

The problem I am attempting to prove is:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be smooth.  Define $\psi$ by $\psi(x)=x^3$

Show $f\circ\psi^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is smooth $\iff\ f^{(n)}(0)=0$ if $n$ is not an integer multiple of $3$.

The problem statement (in case the issue is that I misinterpreted something) is:
Show that $f$ is smooth as a map from $\widetilde{\mathbb{R}}$ to $\mathbb{R}\iff\ f^{(n)}(0)=0$ if $n$ is not an integer multiple of $3$.
Where $\widetilde{\mathbb{R}}$ is the smooth structure determined by the atlas $(\mathbb{R},\psi)$ as defined above.

EDIT: Figured it out